# How to use spatialite SQL functions in GDAL/OGR

Tags: gdal, sql, buffer, ogr, sqlite

I would like to create one-sided buffer geometries around linestrings. I found this [ST_SingleSidedBuffer SpatialLite function](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/libspatialite-4.1.0-RC1/spatialite-sql-4.1.0.html) that I would like to use in my Python script.

When I run the function below, the `bufferFeature` is empty without throwing any error. Is this because I am using an incorrect syntax or because the `ST_functions` cannot be run without setting up a database? I am accessing my data with OGR/GDAL functions.

I couldn't find complete examples online to compare my syntax with, only small snippets from GDAL on [spatialite SQL functions](http://www.gdal.org/ogr_sql_sqlite.html), as well as further ones that seem to require a database connection: [stack exchange: How to use SpatiaLite functions in a Python script?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184850/how-to-use-spatialite-functions-in-a-python-script)

```
def createBuffer(self, datasource, layer, bufferDistance, side): 
 [...]
    for feature in layer:
        geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()

        sqlQuerry = "SELECT ST_SingleSidedBuffer(%s, %.2f , %i) * FROM %s" \
                    % (geometry, bufferDistance, side, layer.GetName())

        bufferFeature = datasource.ExecuteSQL(sqlQuerry, None, 'SQLite')
        #syntax: ExecuteSQL(statement, [spatialFiler], [dialect])
```

Comment: Have a look at the GDAL tests for SQLite dialect at https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/autotest/ogr/ogr_sql_sqlite.py. There seems to be also a test for ST_Buffer though not for ST_SingleSidedBuffer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the correct syntax with which I was able to create a buffered layer:

```
def createBuffer(self, datasource, layer, bufferDistance, side): 
 [...]
    for feature in layer:
        geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()

        bufferLayer = datasource.ExecuteSQL(
        "SELECT ST_SingleSidedBuffer(ST_GeomFromText('%s'), %.2f , %i)" 
        % (geometry, bufferDistance, side), dialect='SQLite')
```

Thanks *@user30184* for pointing out the website in your comment. It seems, I was missing the `ST_GeomFromText` function, while the `FROM` statement is not required here. Further, the SQL statement returns a layer not a feature.