# Make SQL spatial query for GeoPackage with PyQGIS in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, sql, query, geopackage

I am trying to make SQL spatial query for GeoPackage with PyQGIS in my QGIS plugin.

I get error message :

> "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such function: st_envelope"

I can make the query without problem  manually with QGIS "DB Manager". What I am missing ?

It looks like *sqlite3* does not work here. If so - how can I do the query?

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3

geoPack = r 'c:\qgis_dat\mapaIshit\mapaIshit.gpkg'

conn = sqlite3.connect(geoPack)

sql = "select st_astext(st_envelope(geom)) from setl_area where fid = 1 "

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(sql)

column_data = cur.fetchall()   

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue a while back and found this helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/184850/how-to-use-spatialite-functions-in-a-python-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use sqlite3 Python but you'd better use QGIS functions as below

```py
from osgeo import ogr

input_file = '/path/to/geopackage.gpkg'

# To list tables, useful to know the table name in the sql query
# Can be commented
gpkg_layers = [l.GetName() for l in ogr.Open(input_file)]
print(gpkg_layers)

# For info, if GPKG, use "ogr", if spatialite, use "spatialite"
md = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata("ogr")
con = md.createConnection( input_file, {})

result = conn.executeSql('SELECT * FROM youtable')

for row in result:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thomas, thanks it work

Comment: So, accept the answer, plz

Comment: yes . does I must to do  something else ?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of limiting yourself to one specific type of database, why not use a [layer](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html)

```
# get the path to a geopackage  e.g. /usr/share/qgis/resources/data/world_map.gpkg
path_to_gpkg = os.path.join(QgsApplication.pkgDataPath(), "resources", "data", "world_map.gpkg")
# append the layername part
gpkg_countries_layer = path_to_gpkg + "|layername=countries"
# e.g. gpkg_places_layer = "/usr/share/qgis/resources/data/world_map.gpkg|layername=countries"
vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(gpkg_countries_layer, "Countries layer", "ogr")
if not vlayer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```

will get you a layer from a GeoPackage, then you can use a filter to fetch the [features that meet your requirement](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/expressions.html#filtering-a-layer-with-expressions) and then calculate anything you need:

```
expression = 'Test >= 3'
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(expression)

matches = 0
for f in layer.getFeatures(request):
   matches += 1

print(matches)
```

QGis will take care of talking to the underlying datasource (so it will work if you switch to PostGIS or a ShapeFile).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i want to use spatial query on geoPackage because it much more faster(X2-10). I already  have my zoom code for layer:  requestt = QgsFeatureRequest ().setFilterExpression( expressionCur ) 
        it = layer1.getFeatures(requestt) 
        layer1.selectByIds([f.id() for f in it])
        self.iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected(layer1)